# How to display iOS tableview from array data on button press - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have an array that I am trying to use to populate a tableview on a button press (nav bar button). I have used print statements to verify the proper data is present, but I am unable to get the table rows to display on the button press.

I assume the issue lies in my **@IBAction func favoritesButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)** syntax, but now sure how. What am I missing?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var materialData = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(favoritesData)

    }

    @IBAction func arrayList(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print(favoritesData)
    }

    @IBAction func favoritesButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row]
            print(favoritesData)
            return cell
        }
    }
}

var searchMaterial = [String]()
var searching = false
var favoritesData = [String]()

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print(self.materialData[indexPath.row], "selected!")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Favorite") { (action, indexPath) in

            var data: String

            if searching {
                data = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]
                print(searchMaterial[indexPath.row], "added to favorites")
            } else {
                data = self.materialData[indexPath.row]
                print(self.materialData[indexPath.row], "added to favorites")
            }
            if let index = favoritesData.firstIndex(of: data) {
                favoritesData.remove(at: index)
            }
            else {
                favoritesData.append(data)
            }

        }
        favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        return [favorite]
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchMaterial.count
        } else {
            return materialData.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        if searching {
            cell.textLabel?.text = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        searchMaterial = materialData.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do when you push the favorite button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont write `cellForRow` in button action ..
cellForRowAtIndexPath is a method that your `dataSource` provides to the `UITableView`. It is called by iOS to load a cell for a specific indexPath. It works by `dequeueing` a reusable cell and filling in the information for that cell.

You typically do not call this. iOS does so

In your button action just set your DataSource like in your case set `favoritesData` like `favoritesData = data` and then call  `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the info! In your example what does data represent?

Comment: how you assign data to your `favoritesData` variable ?

Comment: have you set your tableView delegate and dataSource ?

Comment: I set favoritesData in editActionsForRowAt via a UITableViewRowAction. Yes I have set up the delegate and datasource

Comment: remove cellForRowAt from `func favoritesButton`

Comment: add another check in your main cell for row ... where you checking for searching or non searching

Comment: please forgive my ignorance. I couldn't even begin to know what check I need to have in that part.

Comment: Create a variable isFavorite .. bool type ... enable it ... when you want to show fav data ... otherwise disable it

Comment: So I created the bool var and added the if statement, but behavior is the same. This is what is in my main cell: if searching {
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = searchMaterial[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        if isFavorite == true {
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = materialData[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }

Comment: but I also don't understand what needs to go in my button func. I can still see the correct data is populating the array. But I just don't know how to display it upon the button press

Comment: and then reload data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213735/discussion-between-jawadali-and-sean-patterson).

Comment: I declared isFavorite = false. Then in my cellForRowAt I have an if isFavorite is true, cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row]. Finally in my IBAction for the button I added isFavorite = true and tableView.reload(). When I click the button the app crashes on the cell.textLabel?.text = favoritesData[indexPath.row] I mentioned above that's part of my isFavorite if statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213888/discussion-between-jawadali-and-sean-patterson).

Comment: Do you need more clarity on this ?